# Modal won't come up on webpage

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to make a modal that is already working on the homepage (index) to work on the rest of the sub-pages, however, for some reason it won't come up. But if I change the name of the modal (so it would be different from the one on the index) it comes up when the page loads and you can't close it.

I have been looking for similar issues and tried many different solutions everywhere but nothing works. Please help me out! :(

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">


    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>TICOPD | Landscapes</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="supersized.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/supersized.shutter.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/supersized.3.2.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/supersized.shutter.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="hover/css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">


    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">


    <style type="text/css">
    ul#demo-block{ margin:0 15px 15px 15px; }
        ul#demo-block li{ margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:10px; display:inline; float:left; clear:both; color:#aaa; background:url('img/bg-black.png'); font:11px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
        ul#demo-block li a{ color:#eee; font-weight:bold; }
</style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>

</head>



<body>
<div id="content">   
        <nav id="menu" style="margin-top: 75px;">
              <ul class="parent-menu">  
                  <li>
                      <a href="index.html" class="hvr-shadow-radial" >Home</a>
                  </li>  
                  <li>
                      <a class="hvr-shadow-radial" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" id="fadeIn">Bio</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
        </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>   
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're loading bootstrap.min.js twice. remove that. and try this `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>`

Comment: I tried and this didn't fix it. Thank you very much for the suggestion tho!

Comment: your modal does not have a proper container.have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tLec49wz/. here i have two modals. one is urs and the other one is mine. update your code accordingly and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all so much for your help! I was able to figure out what the problem was. I replaced:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with version 1.11.2 and that took care of it.

Thank you all again!

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing

```
<a class="hvr-shadow-radial" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" id="fadeIn">Bio</a>
```

with

```
<a href="#" class="hvr-shadow-radial" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="fadeIn">Bio</a>
```

According to the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo).

Hope it's gonna help you.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is, create a php file specific for all your modals, and be sure to import them into your other pages using PHP's include.

```
<?
include('path/to/modals.php');
?>
```

Also include all the modal specific javascript on this page aswell.

And include the modals page near the top of your pages.